# Django 3 and django-select2

Tags: django, django-admin, django-select2

I am curious, since there is select2 implementation in Django admin using autocomplete_fields, why it is not also available outside of admin to my apps?

I am using django-select2 but keep wondering myself am I doing this wrong and cant find any answers around.

**EDIT**

As requested, this are code snippets on how I use django-select2 currently with Django 3.0.6. I have quickly found one that I use with inlineformset_factory, that works:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...,
   'django_select2',
]
```

**urls.py**

```
...
path("select2/", include("django_select2.urls")),
...
```

**forms.py**

```
class SiteMaterialDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SiteMaterialDetails
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'material': Select2Widget,
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class SiteMaterialDetails(models.Model):
    sitematerial = models.ForeignKey(SiteMaterial, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**in template**

```
{% block head %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {{ formset.media.css }}
{% endblock %}

   ...

{{ formset.media.js }}
```

Hope it does make sense :)

Comment: How do you use it? Did you include the `{{ form.media }}` in the template?

Comment: Yes I do @WillemVanOnsem. I mean django-select2 works for me, was just wondering why we cannot use implementation from admin?

Comment: you can, how do you use it? Can you share a (sample) model with form/modeladmin/...

Comment: I will add some snipets to question shortly @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Hope that you will have time to review the code @WillemVanOnsem